# How do I log errors from Xul to a file?

Tags: linux, debugging, logging, xul, xulrunner

I tried export XRE_CONSOLE_LOG as told in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Debugging_a_XULRunner_Application#JavaScript_Console), but had no result.

Also, I would like to see in a file all errors I see in my console (as XPCom errors, not only javascript errors).

**--update**

I'm Running Xulrunner 1.9.2 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing chrome errors but they do not get written to the file you indicated, maybe the file path contains an error? What OS are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Are you correctly set all [developer environment options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences)?